# TYPO3 Extension: How to make a relation to another extension’s model optional?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an events extension (for TYPO3 9 LTS and 10 LTS), say `MyVendor\MyEvents` and a Locations extension, say `MyVendor\MyLocations`.

The Model `MyVendor\MyEvents\Domain\Model\Events` has a property `eventLocation` which is defined to be an object of `MyVendor\MyLocations\Domain\Model\Locations`.

Now I want to make the **relation to** `MyVendor\MyLocations\Domain\Model\Locations` **optional**. I have found a way for the TCA to show a different form field in the backend depending on the MyLocations extension being installed. But I have no idea how to make all the type definitions in the Events model conditional. They are crucial for the extension to work:

```php
namespace MyVendor\MyEvents\Domain\Model

class Events extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var \MyVendor\MyLocations\Domain\Model\Locations
     */
    protected $eventLocation = NULL;

    /**
     * @return \MyVendor\MyLocations\Domain\Model\Locations $eventLocation
     */
    public function getEventLocation()
    {
        return $this->eventLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @param \MyVendor\MyLocations\Domain\Model\Locations $eventLocation
     * @return void
     */
    public function setEventLocation(\MyVendor\MyLocations\Domain\Model\Locations $eventLocation)
    {
        $this->eventLocation = $eventLocation;
    }

}
```

In case `MyVendor\MyLocations` is loaded it needs to be defined as above, in case it isn’t loaded it should be just an integer.

In the TCA I am using `if (TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('my_locations'))` for showing a different field in the backend form for an event.

The Locations Model is in a separate extension because I am using it in a third extension as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your events extension you could setup a repository for locations. Then you can map this repository to your location extensions model via TypoScript.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I’ve added it to the beginning of the post (it’s both 9LTS and 10LTS)